# asp.net webforms app keep loading wrong dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, webforms

I have two versions of a dll. v11.3.3.0 and 11.4. The only difference is they in turn reference different versions of DevExpress dll's. Neither dll is located in the GAC.

The v11.3.3.0 dll is located in a directory named \bin off my main applications root directory. It is used by several programs located in that root directory.

The v11.4 dll is located in the bin directory off the asp.net application which in turn is located in a subdirectory located of the main applications root directory.

The webforms application generally initially loads the v11.4 dll correctly however after it is served up a few times, the webforms application begins to use the v11.3.3.0 version.

How do I force the asp.net application to only use the v11.4 version?

Comment: OK. I have since added the 11.4 dll to the GAC and again the asp.net webforms app is still reverting to the 11.3.3.0 version argh..

Answer (score 0):

You can copy 11.4 `dll` in the bin webforms application.
So use this configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="DllName" publicKeyToken="publicKeyToken" />
                <publisherPolicy apply="no"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That's exactly where it is and I have confirmed neither dll is located anywhere else. 11.3.3.0 is at /bin and 11.4 is at /webservice/htdocs/bin

Comment: Just added that to the web.config file, stoppd and restarted the web server software but didn't make any difference.

Comment: @David please delete  11.3.3.0

Comment: I'd like to BUT it is used by all the other programs so that is not an option. It does fix the issue though because I've already tried and tested it.